# Powershell ConvertTo-JSON returning "nested" object

Tags: json, node.js, powershell

I'm trying to make a POST request to my server. Everything was fine until I decided to convert my object to JSON. Here's my code:

```
$postParams = @{
  Login = "JonSnow66";
  Password = "LetItSnow";
  Email = "Jon.Snow@wall.com";

  Name = "Jon Snow";
  Desc = "I know nothing";
  BirthDate = "1572 2 16";
  Img = Get-Content -Path ./PH_img.txt | Out-String;
  Type = "Admin";
}

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://localhost:3000/api/add/user -Method POST -Body (ConvertTo-Json $postParams -Compress)
```

Instead of returning regular JSON object like:

```
{
"Login": "JonSnow66"
...
}
```

It returns:

```
{{
    "Login":  "JonSnow66",
    "BirthDate":  "1572 2 16",
    "Desc":  "I know nothing",
    "Name":  "Jon Snow",
    "Type":  "Admin",
    "Password":  "LetItSnow",
    "Img":  "/9j/4<BASE64>/Z\r\n",
    "Email":  "Jon.Snow@wall.com"
}: ""}
```

I'm just a powershell beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to specify ContentType on `Invoke-WebRequest` to be 'application/json'. If you don't specify a content type and are performing a Post then I think the cmdlet assumes you are submitting a form by default, and that might explain the extra `{ }` characters you are seeing in the result.

Here's the modified code:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://localhost:3000/api/add/user' -Method POST  -ContentType 'application/json' -Body (ConvertTo-Json $postParams -Compress)
```

Comment: I was literally in the middle of writing Python script for that, thank you.